# Gradient Layer неправильно добавляется на view в IOS

Tags: ios, swift, градиент, uiview

Я пытаюсь добавить слой с градиентом на `View`, но слой добавляется как-то криво и не туда куда надо.

Вот мой код

```
    greenGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    greenGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    greenGradientLayer.frame = gradientImage.frame
    greenGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    greenGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

    gradientImage.layer.addSublayer(greenGradientLayer)
```

И вот что получается. Черное - это мой `View`, зеленое - мой градиент слой. Почему такое происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо попробовать не greenGradientLayer.frame = gradientImage.frame а gradientImage.bounds

Comment: Стало слегка получше, градиент начал рисоваться с нулевых координат, но размеры всё равно чуть бульше чем сам View

Comment: В какой момент вы вызываете этот код, viewDidLoad()? И Используете ли Вы Storyboard?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации. Где добавляете градиент, как добавляете это view.

Comment: Создаю градиент во viewDidLoad(). Добавляю его и во viewDidLoad(), и далее во время работы программы по нажатию кнопки. Результат тот же

Comment: Приложите проект где воспроизводится эта ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
greenGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
greenGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]

gradientImage.layer.insertSublayer(greenGradientLayer, at: 0)

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        greenGradientLayer.frame = gradientImage.frame
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Можно пояснить, почему это не работает в методе viewDidLoad()?

Answer (score 0):

нужно заменить

```
greenGradientLayer.frame = gradientImage.frame
```

на

```
greenGradientLayer.frame = gradientImage.bounds
```

либо заменить

```
gradientImage.layer.addSublayer(greenGradientLayer)
```

на

```
gradientImage.superview.layer.addSublayer(greenGradientLayer)
```

Почему это так.
frame - задает положение вью на его супервью.
т.е. frame у gradientImage на его супервью может быть таким:
x:100,y:200,width:50,height:50
это значит, что градиент будет смещен вправо   на 100 точек, вниз на 200 относительно левого верхнего угла его супервью.
Следовательно, если на greenGradientLayer добавить что-то с таким же как у greenGradientLayer фреймом, то оно будет так же смещено.
у любого вью есть свойство bounds - оно описывает положение и размер в рамках координат самого себя и в данном примере у gradientLayer  bounds будут равны 0,0,50,50, следовательно, если добавить на него что-то с таким же фреймом как у gradientView bounds, то оно будет совмешщено с л евым верхним углом этого градиета